# How to define in a list picker how I want to present the options?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 project in which I have a dictionary.
When I add this dictionary as the datasource of a ListPicker, the listpicker presents the values in this format:
[key,value]
I want to present only one of them. Do you know how could I change it?

Thanks!

Edit1: I could manage to change the info shown when the list is collapsed by changing the DisplayMemberPath property. But when I click on the list, the values are still the toString of the KeyValuePair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed doing it by setting the template with th property FullModeItemTemplate

More on this link

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/customizing-listpicker-for-wp7-part1